# Emacs: how to fix annoying escape behavior when in split windows?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have a really annoying situation; when I'm editing in emacs and the auto-complete box loads up, I find I'm using the escape key to quit out of it when I don't need it. The problem is this has the unwanted behaviour of making the current window the *only* window. This is really annoying when I've set up a number of windows/frames for various tasks.

I'm using `auto-complete.el`, with the following options:

```
(ac-config-default)
(define-key ac-completing-map "\e" 'ac-stop) ; use esc key to exit completion
(global-set-key "\C-f" 'ac-isearch)
```

Since hitting the `ESC` key is in my muscle-memory for dismissing UI elements (drop-downs, dialogs, etc), any idea on how I can hit escape without having the current focussed frame take over?

Comment: As a general measure, add `(winner-mode 1)` to your init file. Then *any* time your window configuration changes unexpectedly, just type `C-c <left>` to restore it.

Comment: Thanks @phils, I've just enabled that. I'd still like a fix for my original question though, as hitting the `ESC` key is in my muscle-memory for dismissing many UI elements.

Comment: @unpluggd Does that ever work in Emacs? Emacs has traditionally its own way of interacting with "UI" elements. You can try to fight it, but it's an uphill battle. I find it much more productive to accept this peculiarity of Emacs, and enjoy its other features. (Its main competition Vim sports similar, if not greater, peculiarities.)

Comment: @user4815162342 I've made a lot of tweaks to emacs that helps it act nicely in an OS X environment. This is one of the few outstanding annoyances I've yet to tame.

Comment: I wish you good luck - seriously :)

Answer (score 3):

In Mac emacs "ESC ESC ESC" is bound to keyboard-escape-quit by default, which is what you're accidentally invoking. This fixed it for me:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "ESC ESC ESC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>C-g</kbd> instead of escape.ff

Comment: That's not answering my question, which is: "how can I hit escape without having the current focussed frame take over?"